# Why does formatting a date return the wrong year?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, date-formatting

I want to print formatted dates on my page. I have an object date and I use $this->Time->format() for formatting. Everything works fine before December 27th. Unfortunately all dates after the December 26th, formatting change my year number.

This is my debug($date)

```
object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

'time' => '2015-12-30T00:00:00+0000',
'timezone' => 'UTC',
'fixedNowTime' => false

}
```

This is my debug($this->Time->format($date, 'YYYY'))

```
'2016'
```

I tried to use i18nFormat but I have the same problem. Here is my debug($date->i18nFormat('YYYY'));

```
'2016'
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 13):

i18n dates are formatted using `IntlDateFormatter`, which use ISO date format patterns, where `YYYY` doesn't just mean **Full year**, but **Full week-numbering year**, wich will return `2016` because the week of the day `2015-12-30` spans into the next year, or more specifically, because that week includes January the 1st that is still a weekday (Monday to Friday), thus it's being treated as the first week of `2016` according to the ISO week rules.

See also **https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates**

You want to use `yyyy` instead, which will return the regular calendar year.

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the date format as `'yyyy'`. The case is important.

```
debug($this->Time->format($date, 'yyyy'))
```