# Cakephp 3.2 change default date format

Tags: date, cakephp, format, date-formatting, cakephp-3.2

I try to set the default date format of CakePHP 3.2 from `dd.mm.YYYY` to `YYYY-mm-dd`, so I will not have to use `$MyDatas->mydate->format('Y-m-d')`, and what is more important in forms while editing data I will have date in format `dd.mm.YYYY` (ex- 27.02.2016). I need `YYYY-mm-dd` (2016-02-27).

I looked for solutions and none display any changes (in forms or as part of view: `$MyDatas->mydate`):

```
// in AppController

ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'pl_PL');

//and/or

use Cake\Database\Type;
Type::build('datetime')->useLocaleParser()->setLocaleFormat('YYYY-mm-dd');

//and/or

use Cake\I18n\I18n;
I18n::locale('pl_PL');

//and/or

use Cake\I18n\Time; 
Time::$defaultLocale = 'pl-PL'; //and or
Time::setToStringFormat('YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm');//and or
Type::build('datetime')->useLocaleParser(false);//and or
```

None of code above helped. Does anyone have any idea how I can change the date format?

Comment: Are the specific columns of type `DATE`, or `DATETIME`?

Comment: in MySQL i have: date_start (DATE), date_end(DATE). For rows in DB where date_start='2016-02-27' cake will display 27.02.2016

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you have been upgrading to CakePHP 3.2, otherwise you'd have seen in your `config/bootstrap.php` file that there are separate types for `DATE`, `DATETIME` and `TIME` type columns.

With CakePHP 3.2 the `date` type doesn't mape to `Cake\I18n\Time` anymore, but to `\Cake\I18n\Date` (or `\Cake\I18n\FrozenDate` when instructed to use immutable objects), and it needs to be configured separately, which is why changing the `datetime` type, or the `\Cake\I18n\Time` class config won't affect your `DATE` columns.

To configure formatting for the latter, use the `\Cake\I18n\Date` and/or `\Cake\I18n\FrozenDate` class and the `date` type. In your bootstrap, you could do something like

```
ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'pl_PL');

// ...

Cake\I18n\Date::setToStringFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
Cake\I18n\FrozenDate::setToStringFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');

\Cake\Database\Type::build('date')
    ->useImmutable()
    ->useLocaleParser()
    ->setLocaleFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

That would override the defaults that are being applied when using the `pl_PL` locale. Note that you should use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY` (as the latter defines the **[week-numbering year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34692446/1392379)**), and `MM` instead of `mm` (as the latter defines minutes).

See **https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#datetime-format-syntax** for the format used by the intl formatter that CakePHP uses internally.

Also note that there's also `\Cake\I18n\Date::$wordFormat` and `\Cake\I18n\Date:$niceFormat` which you may want to change too.

See also

- **[Source > cakephp/app > config/bootstrap.php](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.2.1/config/bootstrap.php#L198-L212)**
- **[API > \Cake\I18n\DateFormatTrait::i18nFormat()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.I18n.DateFormatTrait.html#_i18nFormat)**
- **[API > \Cake\I18n\Date::$wordFormat](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.I18n.Date.html#$wordFormat)**
- **[API > \Cake\I18n\Date::$niceFormat](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.I18n.Date.html#$niceFormat)**
- **[Cookbook > Date & Time > Immutable Dates and Times](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#immutable-dates-and-times)**
- **[Cookbook > Date & Time > Setting the Default Locale and Format String](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#setting-the-default-locale-and-format-string)**
- **[Cookbook > Internationalization & Localization > Parsing Localized Datetime Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#parsing-localized-datetime-data)**

Comment: I clean my AppController.php from my code. I add to bootstrap.php your solution and it did not work. However I changed your Type::build('date') rule by removing ->useImmutable(): Type::build('date')->useLocaleParser()->setLocaleFormat('YYYY-MM-dd'); and it worked! THX

Comment: @MasterAbe `useImmutable()` shouldn't affect parsing/formatting in any way.

Comment: but it does... removing it formats date like i need to, but just adding it will not make change in date format. I tested it in bootstrap and in AppController.

Comment: @MasterAbe Sorry, forgot that `\Cake\I18n\FrozenDate` and `Cake\I18n\Date` do not share the same config. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I did all these configs and it's not working. When I echo in my controller the data is correct: 15/12/2016. But when it goes to the validation rule it says that is an invalid date. I did the configs like you guys said but only changing the format to dd/MM/yyyy. Still not working :( Any solutions? Do I have to parse the string to transform it in date type before goes to the rule validation?

Comment: @Victor Formatting/Parsing and validation are separate things, the latter isn't affected by global built-in configuration: **http://stackoverflow.com/q/34896273/1392379**

Answer (score 4):

after a lot of searching I found.

In the config/app.php under the 'App' => []

change

```
'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'us_US'),
```

to

```
'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'pl_PL'),
```

and all your date will change to your formatting.
because in 
config/boostrap.php
it read

```
ini_set('intl.default_locale', Configure::read('App.defaultLocale'));
```

end in the cake\I18n FrozenDate it set to

```
protected static $_toStringFormat = [IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, -1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code in this file `config/site.php`:

```
return [
 'Site' => [      
        'CakeDateFormat' => 'Y-M-d',
        'DatePickerFormat' => 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        'CakeDateFormatForView' => 'm/d/Y',        
    ]
]
```

Use this date format in controller:

```
use Cake\I18n\Time;

$this->request->data['date'] =Time::parseDate($this->request->data['date'], Configure::read('Site.CakeDateFormat'));
```

Set the date format according to your needs in `CakeDateFormat`.