# Getting CakePHP 3 to output dates in yyyy-mm-dd format

Tags: date, cakephp

CakePHP 3.5.13. I am getting some records from MySQL which are stored as `DATE` fields. For example: `2018-07-30`

I want Cake to output the dates in that format. However, it is converting them to British `dd/mm/yyyy` format. So the example above comes out as `30/07/2018` in my template files.

The data returned from the database looks like this:

```
'date' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenDate) {

        'time' => '2018-07-30T00:00:00+00:00',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
```

In my `config/app.php` the locale is set to `en_GB`:

```
'defaultLocale' => env('APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_GB'),
```

I assume this is the reason it's displaying all of the dates in this way.

All I am doing in the template is displaying the data returned from the database - no conversion is occurring within my code:

```
// In a controller
$RevisionSubstances = TableRegistry::get('RevisionSubstances');
$revision_comments = $RevisionSubstances->find('all')->toArray();
debug($revision_comments); // format is '2018-07-30T00:00:00+00:00'

// In the template
echo $revision_comments['date']; // format is '30/07/2018'
```

How do I get the dates to be output in `yyyy-mm-dd` format?

I had a look at these resources but can't see the answer:

- https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html
- https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#parsing-localized-dates

Comment: See for example **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676227/cakephp-3-2-change-default-date-format** if you want to change the defaults globally.

Comment: @ndm I've looked at that and it works ok for Dates. What if there is a Time involved as well? Some parts of my application use MySQL `DATE` and others have `DATETIME` data, which may also include a time. I still need to output the time with the date portion in the same format, e.g. `2018-07-30 11:15`

Comment: You'd have to additionally configure `\Cake\I18n\Time` and `\Cake\I18n\FrozenTime` accordingly.